# Splitting a 2 dimensional array or a list into two 1 dimensional lists in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, list-comprehension

You have a 2-Dimensional list of numbers like:

```
x = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10],[11,12],[13,14],[15,16],[17,18]]
```

You need to split it into two lists in such a way that you get the numbers from the first column in one list and the second column in another list:

```
[1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17] [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18]
```

How can that be done in python?

I am posting this question because I could not find a simple answer to it.
I will be answering it later.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is the ideal case of using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) as:

```
>>> x = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10],[11,12],[13,14],[15,16],[17,18]]

#       v unpack `x` list
>>> zip(*x)
[(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17), (2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18)]
```

Returned value is a list of two tuples. In order to save each `tuple` in variable, you may do:

```
>>> a, b = zip(*x)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x_1 = [i[0] for i in x]
x_2 = [i[1] for i in x]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [27]: x = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10],[11,12],[13,14],[15,16],[17,18]]

In [28]: first, second = zip(*x)

In [29]: first
Out[29]: (1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17)

In [30]: second
Out[30]: (2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18)
```